# How to make the different instances of class, depending on context?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I have some simple class and some instances for various data types and context. This is a partially working case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances  #-}

class Neighbors a where
     (~~) :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Neighbors Int where
  x ~~ y = (abs (x-y) == 1)

instance (RealFloat a) => Neighbors a where
  x ~~ y = (abs(x-y) < 1.0)
```

There is a disadvantage that is I had to use type restriction for `Int`:

```
*Main> (1::Int) ~~ (2::Int)
True
```

But, if I want use only contexts, my second script isn’t working at all:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances  #-}

class Neighbors a where
     (~~) :: a -> a -> Bool

instance (Integral a) => Neighbors a where
  x ~~ y = (abs(x-y) == 1)

instance (RealFloat a) => Neighbors a where
  x ~~ y = (abs(x-y) < 1.0)
```

Error is:

```
Neighborhood.hs:7:10: error:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance [incoherent] Integral a => Neighbors a
        -- Defined at Neighborhood.hs:7:10
      instance [incoherent] RealFloat a => Neighbors a
        -- Defined at Neighborhood.hs:10:10
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

But I want to define different instances just for these different contexts: Integral and RealFloat. How to do it in one file?

Comment: `1 ~~ 2` can be interpreted as both `(1 :: Double) ~~ (2 :: Double)` and `(1 :: Int) ~~ (2 :: Int)` (numeric literals are overloaded), what do you expect that to do? It's difficult to tell what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want that 1 ~~ 2 will be interpreted as (1 :: Int) ~~ (2 :: Int). But I think it is problem of runtime, not of compilation.

Comment: This illustrates a subtle point about typeclass instance resolution: `instance (C a) => D a` does *not* mean “if `a` has an instance of `C` then `a` also has an instance of `D`”; it means “*all types* have an instance of `D`, which imposes the constraint `C a` on the context where it’s used”.

Comment: Why is `(~~)` defined specially for integral types? What is it actually supposed to *mean*? If you can't express what a class's methods mean, you probably shouldn't have that class.

Comment: If you're doing this to try to learn about defining type classes, then I suggest you don't. Most Haskell programmers *very rarely* define type classes. We define types by the bushel; I wouldn't hesitate to define several types just so I could use them internally in a function implementation. But classes are much rarer. Classes are sometimes used for a sort of metaprogramming, or to create first class constraints for fancy type programming, but most often classes express meaningful concepts. I doubt your `Neighbors` class meets that standard.

Comment: @Jon Prudy, could you possible to say the second part of your comment ( it means "all types have an instance of ``D``, which imposes the constraint ``C a`` on the context where it’s used")  in other words? My English isn't good enough. But first part of your comment brings light on my error in understanding, how typeclass instances work.

Comment: @dfeuer, sometimes we need different behavior of some operations for different sets of values (e.g. "plus" for Int, for Double, for Strings, for Vectors -- sample perhaps not correct in Haskell), of course, I mean overloading. But I had an idea that I could write instances of classes for classes like instances of classes for types. And I've written a small example, which even partially worked.

Comment: @Vladimir: When you write `instance (Constraints) => Class typeExpression`, the compiler *only* uses `typeExpression` to decide which instance of `Class` to choose. *After* selecting an instance, the compiler checks that `Constraints` are satisfied. So when you say `instance (C1 a) => D a` and `instance (C2 a) => D a`, you’re giving the compiler two different instances that both match the same types—in this case, any type `a`—so it doesn’t know which instance to choose. It’s basically the same as if you wrote `instance D Int` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it in one file like this:

```
instance Neighbors Int     where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) == 1
instance Neighbors Double  where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
instance Neighbors Float   where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
instance Neighbors CDouble where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
instance Neighbors CFloat  where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
instance RealFloat a => Neighbors (Identity a) where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
instance RealFloat a => Neighbors (Const a b)  where x ~~ y = abs (x-y) < 1
```

I know you don't like having to write one instance per type constructor; but this is the correct answer to the question as asked nevertheless, as type constructors are the way that Haskell typeclasses do dispatch.

You can reduce some of the repetition by defining

```
neighborsDef :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
neighborsDef x y = abs (x-y) < 1
```

and giving `(~~) = neighborsDef` in the instances.

In fact, stepping slightly to the side of the question as asked, I suspect you do not want a new typeclass at all. Perhaps one of the following two definitions is suitable for you instead:

```
(~~) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
x ~~ y = abs (x-y) <= 1 -- if the Int definition was slightly off, OR
x ~~ y = x /= y && abs (x-y) <= 1 -- if the RealFloat definition was slightly off
```

Comment: Daniel, thank you for answer, I understand than I must make the instances for every type I use. Before it, I thought I could work with instances like in my example above. But maybe, I could work in such manner with Type Families or Type Functional Dependency? And why did you use the instances with ``Identity`` and ``Const`` (they are Monads?) I don't understand how it work and why?

Comment: @Vladimir "Maybe I could work in such manner with {- ... -}?" Sorry, nope. "Why did you use the instances with `Identity` and `Const`?" I just looked at the [list of `RealFloat` instances in the documentation for `base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFloat) and gave an instance of `Neighbors` for each.